# Cannot convert type "char" to "string" in Foreach loop

Tags: asp.net

I have a hidden field that gets populated with a javascript array of ID's. When I try to iterate the hidden field(called "hidExhibitsIDs") it gives me an error(in the title).

this is my loop:

```
foreach(string exhibit in hidExhibitsIDs.Value)
        {
            comLinkExhibitToTask.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExhibitID", exhibit);
        }
```

when I hover over the .value it says it is "string". But when I change the "string exhibit" to  "int exhibit" it works, but gives me an internal error(not important right now).

Comment: This is tagged JavaScript why?

Comment: I thought that maybe there could be a mistake in my javascript

Comment: He's setting the hidden field with a javascript array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert `string` to `string array` to using in for loop to `get strings not characters` as your loop suggests. Assuming comma is delimiter character in the hidden field, hidden field value will be converted to string array by `split`.

```
foreach(string exhibit in hidExhibitsIDs.Value.Split(','))
{
     comLinkExhibitToTask.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExhibitID", exhibit);
}
```

Comment: but now when I run the code in the debugger it shows the ids as "232,232" instead of "232"

Comment: What is the way to do it if I were to make exhibit an int? I've tried int.Parse but it also gives me problems

Answer (score 3):

`Value` is returning a `String`.  When you do a `foreach` on a `String`, it iterates over the individual characters in it.  What does the value actually look like?  You'll have to parse it correctly before you try to use the data.

Example of what your code is somewhat doing right now:

```
var myString = "Hey";
foreach (var c in myString)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Will output:

```
H
e
y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Char.ToString` in order to convert

Link  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d315df2.aspx

Or you can use this if you want convert your tab of char

```
char[] tab = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
string str = new string(tab);
```

Answer (score 1):

On the server side, The `Value` property of a `HiddenField` (or `HtmlInputHidden`) is just a `string`, whose enumerator returns `char` structs. You'll need to split it to iterate over your IDs.

If you set the value of the hidden field on the client side with a JavaScript array, it will be a comma-separated string on the server side, so something like this will work:

```
foreach(string exhibit in hidExhibitsIDs.Value.Split(','))
{
     comLinkExhibitToTask.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExhibitID", exhibit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Value` is a string, which implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so when you `foreach` over a string, it loops over each character.

I would run the debugger and see what the actual value of the hidden field is. It can't be an array, since when the POST happens, it is converted into a string.

Comment: yeah, I have 2 ideas and in the debugger they show up as "232,233" instead of "232".

Comment: when I do (int exhibit in hidExhibitsIDs.Value, why does it not give me a "cannot convert string to int" error? is there a way to parse the .Value to an int?

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static string reversewordsInsentence(string sentence)
        {
            string output = string.Empty;
            string word = string.Empty;
            foreach(char c in sentence)
            {
                if (c == ' ')
                {
                    output = word + ' ' + output;
                    word = string.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    word = word + c;
                }
            }
            output = word + ' ' + output;
            return output;
        }
```